# React useState not updating value in async function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

```
const Login = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    password: ""
  });
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(""); // set empty error state

  const handleChange = event =>
    setData({ ...data, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });

  const handleSubmit = async event => { // async function to handle submit
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      setIsLoading(true);

      const response = await axios.post( // response from server
        "http://localhost:5000/api/users/signup",
        JSON.stringify(data),
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          }
        }
      );
      console.log(response.data); // data comes back fine
      setIsLoading(false);
    } catch (err) {
      const message = err.response.data.message;
      setError(message); // set error message if there is an error
      setIsLoading(false); // always successfully setLoading to false
      console.log(isLoading); // result is false
      console.log(message); // result message
      console.log(error); // result is still empty string. state never updated with message
    }
  };
```

I cant seem to figure out why the error state is not updating in the catch block. I alwasy receive a message and can log the message but the state never updates to the message. I noticed if I submit the form multiple times on the second submit the state will update.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So a few things I see here, first why are you awaiting axios that's already async when you're not doing anything afterwards? And then second, you're not returning anything from the function. Not to say any of that might cause it, but maybe fix those? Like `return axios.post(` instead of `const response...`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I planning on calling a redux action but never got there because I was curious of what was causing this behavior. I ended up using the useEffect hook and everything is working as expected now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any *side-effect*, like network call, data update which is async in nature. You have to use [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect). This will solve the issue. To reuse the logic, You can create *custom hooks*. See the example: [Custom-Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html)

**Use Effect:**

```
useEffect(
  () => {
    const subscription = props.source.subscribe();
    return () => {
      subscription.unsubscribe();
    };
  },
  [props.source],
);
```

**Custom Hook:**

```
function FriendStatus(props) {
  const [isOnline, setIsOnline] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleStatusChange(status) {
      setIsOnline(status.isOnline);
    }

    ChatAPI.subscribeToFriendStatus(props.friend.id, handleStatusChange);
    return () => {
      ChatAPI.unsubscribeFromFriendStatus(props.friend.id, handleStatusChange);
    };
  });

  if (isOnline === null) {
    return 'Loading...';
  }
  return isOnline ? 'Online' : 'Offline';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Removing my Consol.Log's from the catch block to the useEffect block which fires every time error is updated works. Is this the standard way to handle such events? I will be doing more with the code but wanted to make sure I have the correct responses before proceeding

Comment: Nothing specific. Just network call has to be in use effect. Every time you update state. It rerenders code. all the things in function run again. to avoid that better use redux. or complex redux-saga. it will help you a lot. Please check the redux.